# how to divide a scene in two parts?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a scene(view) where I want to divide it in two parts like 80% and 20%.Where one will be the window and other will be having few buttons.how should i do such an implementation?If i press button in one window other window will get effected.

Que: How to divide a scene in two parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cocos2d, there are no windows or divisions of scenes.

You do not divide the scene, you make it look like the screen is divided by placing and sizing your elements appropriately.

At the simplest level, you can have a 384 point high sprite at the top of the screen and some buttons in the lower 96 points which affect the sprite or other elements in the top 80% of the screen.

You may find it beneficial to put the two 'divisions' into different layers.